# Google Drive API to scan document

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I need to include functionality to scan documents into my application. is possible use the new Google drive API to scan documents? I try use OpenCV to process the image but I have not had good results.

Comment: any update how to do this ? I want to capture an image of a document and upload it as if it was scanned. Just the way google drive does. uploading is not concern but the image processing to look like as if it was scanned

Answer (score 0):

By "scan" I assume you mean use OCR to extract text?

The OCR feature on Google Drive is pretty limited.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en

It will scan images or PDFs upto 2MB in size, which isn't much. A single page of text scanned at moderate resolution and stored as JPG format will sometimes be more than that. Reducing the resolution will allow more than one page, but also  make the OCR results less reliable. If you want to store multi-page PDF scans or TIFFs you'll be out of luck.

I tested a single scanned page from an insurance document and it did work, I could (after a few minutes) search on words in the document.

I think you would be better to consider storing the images on Google Drive, after pre-processing with a separate OCR library.

Comment: No, at the moment i dont want extract text using OCR. I want scan images, pre-processing the image, detecting borders.... like drive application. Any idea?

Comment: Alejandro...did you get anywhere with this. I need exactly the same