# Google drive API for Document Scanning

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, image-scanner

I want to include functionality to scan image documents into my application. Is it possible use the new Google Drive API to scan image documents?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797771/google-drive-api-to-scan-document